# advanced form field importing from an excel spreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, excel, forms

I have a .xlsx Microsoft Excel spreadsheet containing thousands of rows, each representing a form field. I need to reconstruct the entire form so that it may be filled out by users and their responses submitted to a MySQL database.

It seems impractical to create a form using for example WordPress plugin NinjaForm, manually creating thousands of fields through the WordPress dashboard. They have functionality for importing, but it seems to be designed only for importing forms that were exported using the ninjaforms UI. The syntax seems complex and undocumented publicly.

I'm not married to the idea of using NinjaForms, but it seems plausible to find some kind of forms creation plugin or software that allows form field importation.

Here's an example of how my data is formatted
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRkz2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

First export to [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) then try this two plugins :

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-csv/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/

I use it with a custom post page and this plugin :
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/